# Websphere traditional location log4j2.properties filesystem

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, websphere

I'm working with Was 8.5 traditional. I'm running it from inside eclipse. Now I'm wondering where I can find the log4j2.properties file,on the filesystem, of the deployed ear. I've looked both in the used profile and the installation of the WAS85 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i found it in my eclipseworkspace:

workspaces\workspacename\metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\app\WEB-INF\classes..